# How to display part of XML file while downloading the rest of the XML

Tags: android, xml

I'm creating a new Android application. I have a big XML file which is basically a big RelativeLayout with multiple ScrollView inside it.

< RelativeLayout >

```
< ScrollView
    ...
    android:visibilty="visible">

</ScrollView>


<ScrollView
    ...
    android:visibilty="gone">

</ScrollView>


<ScrollView
    ...
    android:visibilty="gone">

</ScrollView>

...
```

< /RelativeLayout>

The problem is that this activity takes forever to load (several seconds). As this XML is only composed of several ScrollView and only one of this ScrollView has a "visible" visibilty at a time (the others are "gone"), I would like to display the first ScrollView as soon as it has been loaded without having to wait for the other ScrollViews.

I checked on google and one solution that appeared to be pretty good is to use a "XMLPullParser" (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html). Unfortunately, if I understand well, you can just say to the XMLPullParser to drop some parts of the XML but it has to go through the entier XML file anyway.

Does someone have a solution to my problem ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to have many scrollview in the layout?

Comment: I would like creating a form and the different ScrollView would represent the different steps of completing that form. I would like to put all these ScrollView in one activity so that the client can go to one ScrollView to another and I don't have to save all the information before the client clicks on the button "save" :)